# How can I fix the "kafka" message delay?

Tags: apache-kafka

How can I fix the "kafka" message delay?

If the value of "Lag" does not go down, I think the message is delayed in the generation / consumption.

Is there a way to change the settings or to eliminate message delays with certain commands?

Answer (score 2):

If under delay you really mean consumer lag, then you need to increase number of consumers that process data, but this is could be limited by number of partitions that you have per topic.  You may increase number of partitions & have number of consumers equal to number partitions. You may also re-implement message-processing layer in more effective way, so it will process data in multiple threads, etc.